# \restoregeometry puts one page number wrong

Tags: header-footer, positioning, page-numbering

I am preparing a template, in which I need: 
(1) a custom title page (generated separately)
(2) a custom abstract page with very big footer and no page number
(3) the rest of the document with fancy footer (in particular, including page number) and header.

To achieve (2), I used `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`. However, the page number is placed in correct position only from page 4 onwards, but page 3 has 'wrong' bottom margin size. Any attempts to fix it only wrosen the situation (e.g. align **ALL** page numbers with the 'incorrect' one).
Here is my MWE (at least I hope it's minimal):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside=semi]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=4.79cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Some stuff on title page}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\afterpage{
\newgeometry{bottom=8cm}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcommand{\FooterDisclaimer}{%
    {\parbox[c][5cm]{\textwidth}
        {very long message in footer    
        }
    }
        }   
    \chead{}
    \cfoot{\FooterDisclaimer}
Some stuff on the second page with different footer
\restoregeometry
}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\cfoot{\pagemark}

\section{Test}  
\lipsum[1-20]   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Everything in this comment is untested! No need to use `\afterpage`, instead use `\clearpage\newgeometry{bottom=8cm}<contents of your abstract>\clearpage\restoregeometry`

Comment: If I don't use \afterpage, in fact ALL page numbers are placed wrong :) With \afterpage at least I limit the problem to one page, namely page 3.

Comment: Unrelated: Are the margins required to be that small? Your lines get very long and are hard to read because of that.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I'll double-check the requirements, but apparently they should be small.

Comment: If you put the \restoregeometry after the closing bracket, i.e. three rows down, page 3 seems to look ok.

Comment: I don't know if you haven't noticed or it is wanted: On your title page there is a page number in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Only in the MWE, so I don't mind ;)

Comment: @FredrikJohansson comment is important - one cannot do this, for example, at the end of an environment.  `\restoregeometry` has to be called in`\AfterEndEnvironment` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that KOMA script adjust the `\footheight` for your very large footer on page 2. `\restoregeometry` doesn't set that length back, but only changes the other lengths. The result is a very large footer on the following pages.

To remedy that, put a `\recalctypearea` before `\restoregeometry`, which sets the `\footheight` back to normal (basically this sets everything to the sizes KOMA would use without `geometry`). The `\restoregeometry` resets `geometry`'s sizes.

In code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,twoside=semi]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[top=4.79cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Some stuff on title page}
\maketitle

%% Your second page
\clearpage
  \newgeometry{bottom=8cm}%
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \newcommand{\FooterDisclaimer}
    {%
      \parbox[c][5cm]{\textwidth}
        {\lipsum[1]}%
    }   
    \chead{}
    \cfoot{\FooterDisclaimer}
Some stuff on the second page with different footer

\lipsum[2-5]
\clearpage
%%

\recalctypearea % reset footer height
\restoregeometry % reset page margins
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot{\pagemark}

\section{Test}  
\lipsum[1-20]   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion which avoids the recalculation of `footheight` (and the warning regarding this recalculation):

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=4.79cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm,
  showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot{\pagemark}

\newcommand{\FooterDisclaimer}{%
  \parbox[c][5cm]{\textwidth}{%
    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
    Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
    Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
  }%
}

\newcommand\StartDisclaimerPages
  {%
    \newgeometry{bottom=8cm}\begingroup
    \cfoot{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}
      [\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{\FooterDisclaimer}}%
  }
\newcommand\EndDisclaimerPages
  {\clearpage\endgroup\restoregeometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\title{Some stuff on title page}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\StartDisclaimerPages
\lipsum[1-4]
\EndDisclaimerPages

\section{test}
\lipsum[5-20]
\end{document}
```

Note that I have removed `\pagestyle{gobble}` and the manuel setting of page number 3.

[image]

---

You could also use a new layer pagestyle for the disclaimer page:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[top=4.79cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm,
  showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot{\pagemark}

\newcommand{\FooterDisclaimer}{%
  \parbox[c][5cm]{\textwidth}{%
    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
    Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
    Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
  }%
}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  foot,
  contents={%
    \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagefoot}%
    \FooterDisclaimer
  }
]{disclaimer.foot}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{disclaimer}{disclaimer.foot}

\newcommand\StartDisclaimerPages
  {\newgeometry{bottom=8cm}\begingroup\pagestyle{disclaimer}}
\newcommand\EndDisclaimerPages
  {\clearpage\endgroup\restoregeometry}

\usepackage{lipsum,blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\title{Some stuff on title page}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\StartDisclaimerPages
\lipsum[1-4]
\EndDisclaimerPages

\section{test}
\lipsum[5-20]
\end{document}
```