# \restoregeometry does not immediately restore the geometry on the next page

Tags: koma-script, geometry

The minimal working example below demonstrates a wrong placement of the page number
on the first page after the appearance of the environment `myenv`. How can this be
prevented?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[top=0.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in, bottom=0.5in, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
  \newgeometry{top=0in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in, bottom=0.8in, includehead}
  \cfoot{}
  \rofoot{Page~\thepage}
}{
  % \recalctypearea% doesn't seem to be respected
  \restoregeometry
  % \pagestyle{empty}% doesn't seem to be respected either
}

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
  This is a page from the environment myenv, all fine here.
\end{myenv}
\clearpage
See the wrong placement of the page number at the bottom of this page.
\clearpage
This page is all fine again.
\end{document}
```

You see that two lines in the example are commented out. If you include
them, they have no effect on the problem. The reason I included them is that the
first was mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431455/restoregeometry-puts-one-page-number-wrong)
as a solution to this problem (but doesn't work in my case). The second one also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Probably the same question as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40501/using-restoregeometry-in-environment-next-page-runs-off-the-page-bottom?rq=1 ?

Comment: Thanks, Willie, I searched quite a bit but didn't spot that. Indeed, the solution with `\aftergroup` before `\restoregeometry` worked.